# How to solve a linear system where both inputs are sparse?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

is there any equivalent to `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve` in Julia? Here's the description of the function in Python.

```py
In [59]: ?spsolve                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Signature: spsolve(A, b, permc_spec=None, use_umfpack=True)
Docstring:
Solve the sparse linear system Ax=b, where b may be a vector or a matrix.
```

I couldn't find this in Julia's `LinearAlgebra` and `SparseArrays`. Is there anything I miss or any alternatives?

Thanks

**EDIT**

For example:

```py
In [71]: A = sparse.csc_matrix([[3, 2, 0], [1, -1, 0], [0, 5, 1]], dtype=float)                                                                                                                                    

In [72]: B = sparse.csc_matrix([[2, 0], [-1, 0], [2, 0]], dtype=float)                                                                                                                                             

In [73]: spsolve(A, B).data                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[73]: array([ 1., -3.])

In [74]: spsolve(A, B).toarray()                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[74]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [-3.,  0.]])
```

In Julia, with `\` operator

```
julia> A = Float64.(sparse([3 2 0; 1 -1 0; 0 5 1]))
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 6 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  3.0
  [2, 1]  =  1.0
  [1, 2]  =  2.0
  [2, 2]  =  -1.0
  [3, 2]  =  5.0
  [3, 3]  =  1.0

julia> B = Float64.(sparse([2 0; -1 0; 2 0]))
3×2 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 3 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  2.0
  [2, 1]  =  -1.0
  [3, 1]  =  2.0

julia> A \ B
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching ldiv!(::SuiteSparse.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  ldiv!(::Number, ::AbstractArray) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/LinearAlgebra/src/generic.jl:236
  ldiv!(::SymTridiagonal, ::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T; shift) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/LinearAlgebra/src/tridiag.jl:208
  ldiv!(::LU{T,Tridiagonal{T,V}}, ::Union{AbstractArray{T,1}, AbstractArray{T,2}} where T) where {T, V} at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/LinearAlgebra/src/lu.jl:588
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] \(::SuiteSparse.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/LinearAlgebra/src/factorization.jl:99
 [2] \(::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/SparseArrays/src/linalg.jl:1430
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[81]:1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's the `\` function.

```
julia> using SparseArrays, LinearAlgebra

julia> A = sprand(Float64, 20, 20, 0.01) + I # just adding the identity matrix so A is non-singular.

julia> typeof(A)
SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}

julia> v = rand(20);

julia> A \ v
20-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5930744938331236
 0.8726507741810358
 0.6846427450637211
 0.3135234897986168
 0.8366321472466727
 0.11338490488638651
 0.3679058951515244
 0.4931583108292607
 0.3057947282994271
 0.27481281228206955
 0.888942874188458
 0.905356044150361
 0.17546911165214607
 0.13636389619386557
 0.9607381212005248
 0.2518153541168824
 0.6237205353883974
 0.6588050295549153
 0.14748809413104935
 0.9806131247053784
```

---

Edit in response to question edit:

If you want `v` here to instead be a sparse matrix `B`, then we can proceed by using the `QR` decomposition of `B` (note that cases where `B` is truly sparse are rare:

```
function myspsolve(A, B)
    qrB = qr(B)
    Q, R = qrB.Q, qrB.R
    R = [R; zeros(size(Q, 2) - size(R, 1), size(R, 2))]
    A\Q * R
end
```

now:

```
julia> A = Float64.(sparse([3 2 0; 1 -1 0; 0 5 1]))
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 6 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  3.0
  [2, 1]  =  1.0
  [1, 2]  =  2.0
  [2, 2]  =  -1.0
  [3, 2]  =  5.0
  [3, 3]  =  1.0

julia> B = Float64.(sparse([2 0; -1 0; 2 0]))
3×2 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 3 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  2.0
  [2, 1]  =  -1.0
  [3, 1]  =  2.0


julia> mysolve(A, B)
3×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0  0.0
  1.0  0.0
 -3.0  0.0
```

and we can test to make sure we did it right:

```
julia> mysolve(A, B) ≈ A \ collect(B)
true
```

Comment: Thanks! See the example my updated question, I couldn't seem to get this working in Julia..

Comment: Are you sure your `B` needs to be sparse? I think your best bet is to convert `B` to dense because almost no matter what, `A\B` is going to end up being dense anyways and that’s what Julia supports out of the box. There may be a way to do this while keeping `B` dense but I don’t know.

Comment: Thanks! That's not the real use case for now, but it's from `spsolve` docstring example. If that's the case then that's fine :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to solve this in the case where `B` is sparse. Can you please edit the question title to something a bit more searchable? How about "how to solve a linear system where both inputs are sparse?"

Comment: For sure! Thanks a lot!